# Trouble making a good ftp checking python program

Tags: python, datetime, ftp, uploading, download

Please bear with me. Its only been a week I started on python. Heres the problem: I want to connect to a FTP Server. Presuming the file structure on my ftp and local directory is same. I want my python program to do the following:

1> On running the program, it should upload all the files that are NOT on the server but on my 
local(Upload just the missing files-Not replacing all). 
Say, I add a new directory or a new file, it should be uploaded on the server as it is.
2> It should then check for modified times of both the files on the local and the server and inform which is the latest.

NOw, I have made two programs:

1>One program that will upload ALL files from local to server, as it is. I would rather it check for missing files and then uipload just the missing files folders. NOt replace all.
2> Second program will list all files from the local, using os.walk and it will upload all files on the server without creating the correct directory structure.
 All get copied to the root of server. Then it also checks for modified times.

I am in amess right now trying to JOIN these two modules into one perfect that does all I want it to.Anyone who could actually look at these codes and try joining them to what I wanana do, would be perfect. Sorry for being such a pain!!

PS:I might have not done everything the easy way!!

Code NO 1:

```
import sys

from ftplib import FTP

import os

def uploadDir(localdir,ftp):

    """

    for each directory in an entire tree

    upload simple files, recur into subdirectories

    """

    localfiles = os.listdir(localdir)

    for localname in localfiles:

        localpath = os.path.join(localdir, localname)


        print ('uploading', localpath, 'to', localname)
        if not os.path.isdir(localpath):

            os.chdir(localdir)


            ftp.storbinary('STOR '+localname, open(localname, 'rb'))



        else:

            try:

                ftp.mkd(localname)

                print ('directory created')

            except:

                print ('directory not created')

            ftp.cwd(localname)             # change remote dir

            uploadDir(localpath,ftp)                  # upload local subdir

            ftp.cwd('..')                  # change back up

            print ('directory exited')


def Connect(path):
  ftp = FTP("127.0.0.1")
  print ('Logging in.')
  ftp.login('User', 'Pass')
  uploadDir(path,ftp)


Connect("C:\\temp\\NVIDIA\\Test")
```

Code No2:

```
import os,pytz,smtplib
import time
from ftplib import FTP
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from email.mime.text import MIMEText



def Connect_FTP(fileName,pathToFile):                       path from the local path
(dir,file) = os.path.split(fileName)

fo = open("D:\log.txt", "a+")                        # LOgging Important Events
os.chdir(dir)
ftp = FTP("127.0.0.1")
print ('Logging in.')
ftp.login('User', 'Pass')
l=dir.split(pathToFile)
print(l[1])

if file in ftp.nlst():                                          
print("file2Check:"+file)
    fo.write(str(datetime.now())+":  File is in the Server. Checking the Versions....\n")
    Check_Latest(file,fileName,ftp,fo)
else:
    print("File is not on the Server. So it is being uploaded!!!")
    fo.write(str(datetime.now())+":  File is NOT in the Server. It is being Uploaded NOW\n")
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+file, open(file, 'rb'))


print("The End")


def Check_Latest(file2,path_on_local,ftp,fo):                               # Function to check the latest file, USING the "MOdified TIme"
LOcalFile = os.path.getmtime(path_on_local)
dloc=datetime.fromtimestamp(LOcalFile).strftime("%d %m %Y %H:%M:%S")
print("Local File:"+dloc)
localTimestamp=str(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(dloc, "%d %m %Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple())) # Timestamp to compare LOcalTime


modifiedTime = ftp.sendcmd('MDTM '+file2)                             # Using MDTM command to get the MOdified time.
IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
ServTime=datetime.strptime(modifiedTime[4:], "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

tz = pytz.timezone("UTC")
ServTime = tz.localize(ServTime)
j=str(ServTime.astimezone(IST))                                       # Changing TimeZone
g=datetime.strptime(j[:-6],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
ServerTime = g.strftime('%d %m %Y %H:%M:%S')
serverTimestamp=str(time.mktime(datetime.strptime(ServerTime, "%d %m %Y %H:%M:%S").timetuple())) # Timestamp to compare Servertime

print("ServerFile:"+ServerTime)

if serverTimestamp > localTimestamp:
  print ("Old Version on The Client. You need to update your copy of the file")
  fo.write(str(datetime.now())+":  Old Version of the file "+file2+" on the Client\n")
  return
else:
  print ("The File on the Server is Outdated!!!New COpy Uploaded")
  fo.write(str(datetime.now())+": The server has an outdated file: "+file2+". An email is being generated\n")
  ftp.storbinary('STOR '+file2, open(file2, 'rb'))

def Connect(pathToFile):

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(pathToFile):
 for name in files:
    j=os.path.join(path, name)
    print(j)
    Connect_FTP(j,pathToFile)
```

Connect("C:\temp\NVIDIA\Test")

Answer (score 0):

May be [this script](http://code.google.com/p/ftpsync2d/) will be useful.

Comment: Thank you for that. I will definitely have a look at it. Also, codes above are my own and you think I could actuyally make a syncing program using them. All the features needed are ther its just that I am unable to join them to one.